# Как в T-SQL пройти по дереву?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица, она представляет собой структуру файлов и папок.
Там есть поля id, id_parent, file_name_cl. Некоторые записи ссылаются на другие записи этой же таблицы через id_parent (как файлы в папке). Так же у меня есть строка такого вида: "\Имя\Имя2\Имя3", это так сказать путь до конечного файла в таблице. Подскажите как мне написать запрос или функцию, чтобы передав ему такую строку, я смог получить искомый файл? Строку я могу разбить в массив имён, вне T-SQL и думаю передать в виде таблицы тоже, но как мне пройтись по дереву, слабо представляю...

**UPDATE**: Получилось сделать вот в таком виде:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FullPathType] AS TABLE(idx int, Name nvarchar(1000) not null)
GO

CREATE function [dbo].[GetFileByFullPath] (@full_path dbo.FullPathType readonly)
returns int
begin
  DECLARE @i int
  DECLARE @count_rows int
  DECLARE @current_parent_id int
  DECLARE @current_name nvarchar(1000)

  SET @i = 1
  SET @current_parent_id = null
  SET @count_rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @full_path)
  IF @count_rows > 0
    while (@i<=(select max(idx) from @full_path))
      begin
        SET @current_name = (SELECT Name FROM @full_path WHERE idx = @i)
        SET @current_parent_id = (select id from Files where file_name_cl=@current_name and id_parent=@current_parent_id)
        SET @i=@i+1
      end

RETURN @current_parent_id;
end
go
```

Comment: Рекурсивные CTE.

Comment: @Akina примерчик можно?

Comment: Вверху в строке поиска введите `[sql-server] рекурсивный дерево` и изучите найденные темы.

Comment: @Akina, не получается с рекурсией, нужен скорее цикл по таблице которую я передаю в параметрах

Comment: Ну чему тут не получаться-то? строите рекурсивно от корня всё дерево (можно ограничиться уровнем, который у искомого ресурса), и соответственно полные пути узлов, и в полученном ищете заданный путь.

Comment: @Akina кое что поделал, но есть ошибка

Comment: Ну так добавляйте информацию в вопрос-то... *UPDATE: сделал то-то, вот текст запроса, вот сообщение об ошибке...* И, чтобы два раза не бегать, DDL таблицы добавьте, с тестовым наполнением и желаемым для него выводом (или линк на fiddle).

Comment: @Akina спасибо за помощь, всё заработало, ответ добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С некоторой помощь решил:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FullPathType] AS TABLE(idx int, Name nvarchar(1000) not null)
GO

CREATE function [dbo].[GetFileByFullPath] (@full_path dbo.FullPathType readonly)
returns int
begin
  DECLARE @i int
  DECLARE @count_rows int
  DECLARE @current_parent_id int
  DECLARE @current_name nvarchar(1000)

  SET @i = 1
  SET @current_parent_id = null
  SET @count_rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @full_path)
  IF @count_rows > 0
    while (@i<=(select max(idx) from @full_path))
      begin
        SET @current_name = (SELECT Name FROM @full_path WHERE idx = @i)
        SET @current_parent_id = (select id from Files where file_name_cl=@current_name and id_parent=@current_parent_id)
        SET @i=@i+1
      end

RETURN @current_parent_id;
end
go
```